# How to disable/enable WS-Security for some server methods only with CXF?

Tags: cxf, ws-security

I'm configuring WS-Security for my web service with Apache CXF. I've added `WSS4JInInterceptor` and callback and it's working. The problem is that some methods don't require to be protected by WS-Security and some should.

How can i do that way? Any annotations or input map keys for WSS4JInInterceptor?

I can see in WSS4jInInterceptor code:

```
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage msg) throws Fault {
        if (msg.containsKey(SECURITY_PROCESSED) || isGET(msg)) {
            return;
        }
```

So it seems i can add my custom interceptor and add `SECURITY_PROCESSED` to unprotected methods, but it seems that there is better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now i had to reinvent the wheel with my own `Interceptor` impl:

```
    // adds skip flag for methods that should not be checked
    public static class CheckMethodsInterceptor implements PhaseInterceptor<SoapMessage> {

        private List<String> checkedMethods;

        public CheckMethodsInterceptor(List<String> checkedMethods) {
            this.checkedMethods = checkedMethods;
        }

        protected void allowConnection(SoapMessage message) {
            // skip checking by WSS4JInInterceptor
            message.put(WSS4JInInterceptor.SECURITY_PROCESSED, "true");
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
            String action = (String)message.get("SOAPAction");
            if (action == null || !checkedMethods.contains(action.substring(action.lastIndexOf("/") + 1))) {
                allowConnection(message);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Set<String> getAfter() {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }

        @Override
        public Set<String> getBefore() {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }

        @Override
        public String getId() {
            return CheckMethodsInterceptor.class.getName();
        }

        @Override
        public String getPhase() {
            return Phase.PRE_PROTOCOL;
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<PhaseInterceptor<? extends Message>> getAdditionalInterceptors() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleFault(SoapMessage message) {

        }
    }
```

and use it like this:

```
    // checked methods only (before WSS4JInInterceptor !)
    SecurityService.CheckMethodsInterceptor checkMethodsInterceptor =
        new SecurityService.CheckMethodsInterceptor(Arrays.asList(
            "CreateUsers",
            "GetUsers"
        ));
    ep.getServer().getEndpoint().getInInterceptors().add(checkMethodsInterceptor);

    WSS4JInInterceptor inSecurityInterceptor = new WSS4JInInterceptor(inSecurityProperties);
```

Feel free to suggest better solution.